# Include exceptions in activity diagrams?

Tags: c#, design, .net, exceptions, activity

Should I include exceptions, like a TimeOutException or just general Exceptions, to a activity diagram?

For example: A activity diagram describing a client-server connection. Several exceptions can be thrown and in my software I use the Enterprise Library to handle/log it. Should I include the exception handling and if so how? 
I already documented the connection between excpetion handling and the rest using component diagrams.

Comment: And should be validating inputs also be a part of activity diagrams?
If a validation fails/be invalid the software shows an message, but if a exception is thrown it will be handled and (in 80% of the cases) it won't be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would include them when the exception affects the users actions. Ie. If the timeout causes the user to have to re-login.

I think you have another underlying question though. "How detailed should my activity diagrams be?" Which is much harder to answer.

On one hand you can virtualy write the code in UML and cover all the edge cases. But on the other, the usefulness of these diagrams over the raw code is that they are supposed to be easy to read and understand. If you put too much on them that goal is degraded